# LinqToTwitter query tweets by user ID

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I want to query tweets by **user ID**. I implemented the code to query tweets by username with using *from* operator in the query:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(twitterUsername)) {
      var searchResponse = (from srch in twitterContext.Search where  
        srch.Type == SearchType.Search &&
        srch.Query == "some text from:" + twitterUsername 
        select srch).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Now I need the code which will query tweets by **user ID**, but I cannot find any solution except to call twitter `API` to get tweeter username by **user ID** and then call the code above with returned username.

Is there any simpler solution, with one `API` call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Status/User query, like this:

```
        var tweets =
            await
            (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
             where tweet.Type == StatusType.User &&
                   tweet.UserID == twitterUserId
             select tweet)
            .ToListAsync();
```

You can get more details in the [LINQ to Twitter Documentation](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/wiki/Querying-the-User-Timeline).